# Swiftui function to change variable

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to update a variable (change it from 1 to 0 or vice versa) at different points.

I have an observable object:

```swift
    class GameSettings: ObservableObject {
    @Published var score = 1
    @Published var alert = 0
    @Published var displayNavButtons = 1
}
```

a function to change displayNavButtons:

```swift
    func toggleNavButtonsOff(gamesettings: inout GameSettings) {
    let gamesettings = gamesettings
    gamesettings.displayNavButtons = 0
}
```

and a view:

```swift
    struct PageRender: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var settings: GameSettings
    var body: some View {

    if settings.score == 1 {

    toggleNavButtonOff(game settings: &settings)
    Text ("page 1")
    ...
    }
    }
    }
```

I will also have another function called toggleNavButtonOn, to change displayNavButtons to 1 again.

Elsewhere in the code (...) there is an if statement to selectively display some buttons (the NavButtons) and clicking these buttons increases or decreases the "score" by 1 (that all works as expected). The idea is to display the NavButtons if displayNavButtons = 1. But if displayNavButtons = 0 however, i'd like it so the buttons aren't displayed. I need to vary displayNavButtons based on certain criteria.

However, implementing the above doesn't seem to work. Calling the function within the view gives the error: "Type '()' cannot conform to 'View'; only struct/enum/class types can conform to protocols" and "Cannot pass immutable value as inout argument: 'settings' is a get-only property".

Does anyone have any idea how to solve this? Thanks

Comment: "Type '()' cannot conform to 'View'" put `if settings.score == 1 {` inside a `Group`

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
struct PageRender: View {
  @EnvironmentObject var settings: GameSettings
  
  var body: some View {
    Group {
      if settings.score == 1 {
        Text ("page 1")
      }
    }.onAppear {
      settings.toggleNavButtonOff()
    }
  }
}

class GameSettings: ObservableObject {
  @Published var score = 1
  @Published var alert = 0
  @Published var displayNavButtons = 1

  func toggleNavButtonsOff() {
    self.dispalyNavButtons = 0
  }
}
```

As @aheze eluded to in the comments, the compiler doesn't seem to like having *just* an `if` statement in the `body`, as nothing gets returned if the condition is false. The `Group` prevents this.

I used `onAppear` instead of calling the toggle function inline, which doesn't make much sense any way -- views in SwiftUI can get rendered *many* times and you generally don't want to interlace imperative code in your declarative view hierarchy.

Comment: Thanks for you help. Unfortunately that doesn't seem to work. It can't access the function - it just doesn't recognise it when you call it from PageRender view

Comment: Sorry — I had forgotten to call it on the view model. Please try again.